# Get image url from twitter api entity parameter php

Tags: php, image, twitter, entities

I'm attempting to get and display images posted in a tweet with php via the entities parameter. I have include_entities in my url and can see the entities in the returned json.

In my foreach loop, I am doing the following:

```
foreach($results as $result){
    $media_url = $result->entities->media->media_url;
    $media_size_h = $result->entities->media->sizes->small->h;
    $media_size_w = $result->entities->media->sizes->small->w;
...
}
```

However, this is not returning anything.

For my output, I have...

```
if(strlen($media_url) > 0)
{
    //format table for tweets with images

} else {
    //format table for regular tweets 
}
```

And this is the json...

```
array(20) {
[0]=>
object(stdClass)#5 (21) {
...
["entities"]=>
object(stdClass)#7 (4) {
  ["media"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#8 (10) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(5) "photo"
      ["media_url"]=>
      string(38) "http://photourl.jpg"
...
["sizes"]=>
      object(stdClass)#9 (4) {
        ["thumb"]=>
        object(stdClass)#10 (3) {
          ["resize"]=>
          string(4) "crop"
          ["h"]=>
          int(150)
          ["w"]=>
          int(150)
        }
...
}
```

Any ideas why this is not working? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$result->entities->media->`   this is an array as seen in structure... try using

```
$media_url = $result->entities->media[0]->media_url;
```

Comment: Hi i am not getting media_url field value as i wrote here -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471417/getting-user-tweets-by-twitter-api-call-not-returning-media-url

Comment: The API was changed not so long ago. Now days, if you want the media url you will need to do: 
`$result->media[0]->media_url;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = json_decode($results);
```

I think that's much easier to see how to select items when you decode json objects :)

Try that next time :)

Comment: Lol, nub. Everything is correct.. Mind your reading next time.

Comment: it's correct now, _after_ my edit .. check the differences, mate

Answer (score -1):

I could very well be wrong but I believe you need [] before and after numbers in if statements.